# Why does navbar back button still show with ActionConst.REPLACE in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-router-flux

I start with Login scene, and when I click a button with `Actions.home`, `type={ActionConst.REPLACE}`, it works fine and on the Home scene the navigation bar does not have a back button. But if I go from Login to Register to RegisterTwo then to Home, the Home scene's navigation bar has a back button.

What is causing the issue? I tried just `type='replace'` and the back button still shows in the navigation bar.

My scenes are set up like so:

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' title='Login'/>
            <Scene component={Register} key='register' title='Register'/>
            <Scene component={RegisterTwo} key='registerTwo' title='Register Two'/>
            <Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home' type={ActionConst.REPLACE}/>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

I simply use `import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'` and `Action.key` to navigate.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
<Scene component={Home} key='home' title='Home' type="reset"/>
```

or in your navigation action

```
Action.home({type:'reset'})
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Before I accept the answer and upvote, just a few quick questions, what would be the main difference between reset and replace? And when would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Reset is similar to replace except it unmounts the componets in the navigator stack.

Comment: Reset is similar to replace except it unmounts the components in the navigator stack.

'"reset" must be used in case you want to reset the navigator stack. "replace" is for replacing a current view and add an old view in navigator stack, it's similar to "Action.key".
 You can look this page for more information: 
[link](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md)

Comment: Got it so just to confirm. After logging in, resetting the stack would typically be the correct thing to do, correct?

Comment: Yes. You check if a user is connected and if user is connected you redirect user in mainscreen and reset a stack. When user logout you redirect user in login screen and reset a stack.